# How to call PowerShell script with azure commands in C# windows application

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, powershell-4.0

Below is my event, where, if I pass, simple powershell script it runs fine, but if I pass script contains any Azure commands, output is blank. (That azure command script is running fine from powershell command prompt)

```
private void RunScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string result = "";

        PSDataCollection<PSObject> myOutPut = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();

        try
        {
            InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] {
                        @"C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\5.2.0\AzureRM.psd1",
                });

            using (Runspace objRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial))
            {
                objRunSpace.Open();

                using (PowerShell objPowerShell = PowerShell.Create())
                {

                    objPowerShell.Runspace = objRunSpace;

                    string Script = textBoxURL.Text;                        

                    objPowerShell.AddScript(Script);

                    objPowerShell.AddCommand("Out-String");

                    IAsyncResult IvokeResult = objPowerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, myOutPut);

                    while (IvokeResult.IsCompleted == false)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }

                    foreach (PSObject outitem in myOutPut)
                    {
                        result += outitem.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            textBoxOutPut.Text = result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why running PowerShell from C# when you have C# client for Azure REST API? You can call Azure API without middle layer of PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, there is no issue with you mentioned code. I can get empty output if input a wrong command. So please make sure that your command is correct.

Another import thing is that make sure that the command it has ouput. I test the azure command [Add-AzureRmAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/add-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-5.2.0#outputs).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where is you connection to Azure?

You load the module, but you have nothing establishing a connection to Azure to use the cmdlets.

In your native PoSH instance/session, you'd to have this to work:

```
# Set creds
$AdminCreds = Get-Credential -Credential 'admin@domain.com'

# Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Admincreds


Account                          Environment TenantId   TenantDomain            AccountType
-------                          ----------- --------   ------------            -----------
admin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com    AzureCloud  11...      contoso.onmicrosoft.com User
```

If not, you'd end up with errors like this...

```
Get-AzureADApplication
Get-AzureADApplication : You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureADApplication
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @postanote.
but, i am using, following line in my powershell script. 

 Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $azurecred -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId

running this script in powershell works absolutely fine.

I also did change into my script, to load whole script rather then just giving file path. But same result. myOutPut variable doesn't get anything into it.

Comment: OoooK, I have not seen / used this cmdlet since I been using PoSH with AzureAD, hence the cmdlet I posted back with. Looking on dev workstation and servers where I have the original AzureAD cmdlets installed. This is not one of them. A quick look at the MSDOCS site for AzurePowerShell, shows this as a different install. So, I guess I need to get those on a system and try them first. Connect-AzureAD is quick simple and to the point, and probably the reason I had not looked at the AzureRM bits. So, time to play with them and see what the deal is.